# Abelian group of type $(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_t).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of type $(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_t).$

1. Prove that $G$ contains an element of order $m$ if and only if
   $m\mid n_1;$
2. Deduce that $G$ is of exponent $n_1;$
3. Does a finite group of exponent $m$ always contain an element of order $m?$

IF $p$ is prime then task 1. But I **can't  prove 1 for arbitrary $n$.** I have no idea how to start it. Help me, please.

Statement "$G$ is of exponent $n_1$" deduces from 1 and definition of exponent of a group.

From 1 and 2 we have that any finite abelian group of exponent $m$ contains an element of order $m.$ What about non-abelian?

Comment: What  exactly do you mean by a free abelian group of type $(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_t)$?

Comment: @DerekHolt abelian group $G$ is called group of type $(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_t)$ if there are integer $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_t$ such that 1) $G=Z_{n_1} \times Z_{n_2} \times \ldots  \times Z_{n_t}$ 2)$n_j \geq 2$ for all j and 3)  $n_{j+1}\mid n_j;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assume that $m$ divides $n_1$ and take $e_1$ a generator of $G$ of order $n_1$ (see your definition of an abelian group of given type). Then I claim that $\frac{n_1}{m}e_1$ is of order $m$. This is for the $\Leftarrow$ implication.

For the other implication. Define $e_i$ the generator of order $n_i$. Any element of $g\in G$ can be written as $g=a_1e_1+...+a_te_t$ (additive notation). Now in any abelian group $A$, if $a,b\in A$ then the order of $a+b$ divides the lcm of the order of $a$ and the order of $b$. Use this last property to show that the order of $g$ will divide the lcm of $n_1$,...,$n_t$.

2. The exponent is the lcm of all order of all elements in the group, by 1 this divides $n_1$, now we have an element of order $n_1$ in $G$...
3. Hint : Show that this is false for $G=D_3$ the dihedral group of order $6$ (this is the first non abelian) or $S_3$ the symmetric group over $3$ elements (those groups are the same).